# Open Link from Command Line in existing IE Window

Tags: authentication, session, internet-explorer, browser, hyperlink

I need to achieve the following.

My clients navigate to a webpage in Firefox where the click a link which brings them to a login page that needs to open in IE.

That part i could get done without problems- so far so good.

If they click the Link in Firefox AGAIN a NEW iexplorer Winow opens where they have to put in the Login Information again, although there is an existing Session of IE already running.

The way this is achieved is a command line that starts iexplorer like this:

start iexplore "url" -sessionmerging -framemerging

Even though i used the parameters it always needs the Login information over and over again.

If i manually open the link in the Window where they once logged in, it WORKS!

So what i am trying to achieve is, to get the command line to use the EXISTING IE Winow instead of opening a new window when they click on the Link in Firefox.

Is there any chance to get this to work?

Sidenote: it should work even though IE is NOT the default browser.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I try to search for a command but did not got any example for it.

Here, I found powershell script which is working as per your requirement and it is opening the link in the existing IE window.

```
$navOpenInNewTab = 0x800

# Get running Internet Explorer instances
$App = New-Object -ComObject shell.application

# Grab the last opened tab
$IE = $App.Windows() | Select-Object -Last 1

# Open link in the new tab nearby
$IE.navigate('http://bing.com', $navOpenInNewTab)

# Cleanup
'App', 'IE' | ForEach-Object {Remove-Variable $_ -Force}
```

Reference:

[Open a URL file in a new tab of existing IE window from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/601850/open-a-url-file-in-a-new-tab-of-existing-ie-window-from-command-line)